# How to use a JS variable in a url using template strings?

Tags: javascript, html, api

I'm trying to put a variable (city name) into a .fetch url to get the weather for that city variable.

When I first declare the variable with a value it works, but when I make the variable the .value of the input box, it doesn't work.

I have also tried `JSON.stringify(value)`

```
let input = document.querySelector("input").value;

async function getWeather() {
  let response = await fetch(
`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${input}&APPID=123&units=metric`);

...

button.addEventListener("click", getWeather, { once: true });
```

As you can see I am placing the variable where the city name usually goes, but to no avail.

The output should return the weather for that city (code for this not shown) but instead I get a console error GET url 400 (bad request)

Comment: Move the `let input = document.querySelector("input").value` inside the `getWeather` function

Comment: Also you should use `encodeURIComponent` to escape input value.

Comment: thanks adiga, @YuryTarabanko what does that do exactly?

Comment: @ksingh This would encode input value to be safe to put in URL. For example it would properly escape spaces, ampersands if user input any.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko makes sense, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only read the value once when the script runs initially and then you never update it. Reading the `value` property of an input and assigning it to a variable simply copies the current string value to the variable, it’s not a reference so the variable won’t update when the input changes.

Just read the value in your event handler:

```
async function getWeather() {
  let input = document.querySelector("input").value;
  let response = await fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${input}&APPID=123&units=metric`);
```

Comment: Thank you @Lennholm, this way the value also gets updated each time the function runs.

Answer (score 0):

log the Input variable, maybe it's undefined:

```
async function getWeather() {
let url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${input}&APPID=123&units=metric`; 
console.log(link, "<--Link | Input-->", input);
  let response = await fetch(url);
```